# How to notify iPhone client that server has new updates?

Tags: iphone, notifications, refresh, push, updates

I am working on this iPhone app that connects to web services and receives data from a server. Whenever server has new updates, I would like iPhone client to show user that there's new stuff on server, and they can refresh the view.

I know this could be done with push notifications. But would also like this to work out on situation when user turned off push notifications on his iPhone.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use Push notification for this if you want to inform the user of an update if the app ins't open.

You can of course display a UIAlertview if the app is opened, or just update the view with a nice animation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! the scenario is like this.. when the app is open, and without using push notifications.. how can the iPhone client know there's updates on server? Starting a timer and send request to server periodically? Doesn't it drain the battery? Thanks!

Comment: There is no way to allow the server to push data to the client with out push notifications. Thus periodically check for an update on the server is the only way to go, if possible build something  like the pull to refresh. Then the user is in control of the update time.

Comment: I see, was just wondering if there's any better way to do this.. Thanks for the help! :)